# What is the best way to scrape content rendered by a Chrome Extension?

Tags: reactjs, web-scraping, google-chrome-extension

I want to scrape the content rendered/showed by a Chrome Extension - not a website. The webpage URL triggers a request to this specific Chrome Extension, and they render content that comes from their database.

I'm trying to automate the current workflow we have.

What are the best tools and ways for this task?

Thanks & Love.

Comment: Puppeteer should work I think.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on what you are trying to accomplish. Do you need to interact with the content after it is rendered by the extension? You may be able to use something like Cypress: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress